Modular conjugation with respect to a normal faithful state

According to Tomita's theorem，we have $JMJ=M'$.
I wonder the relationship between $JM_{\omega}J$ and $M_{\omega}'$, where $\omega$ is a faithful normal state on $M$. Is it possible that $JM_{\omega}J=M_{\omega}'$ when $\omega$ is not tracial?

By $M_\omega$, I presume you meant the centralizer of a state $\omega$? Then no, if $\omega$ is not tracial, $M_\omega$ is a strict subalgebra of $M$, so $J M_\omega J$ is a strict subalgebra of $JMJ = M’$, but $M’ \subset M_\omega’$. (In fact, by double commutant theorem, $M_\omega’$ is a strict superalgebra of $M’$.)

$M_\omega'$ is a strict superalgebra of $M'$? But we know that $M'\subset M_\omega'$?

Yes? I wrote “superalgebra”, not “subalgebra”. By $M_\omega’$ being a strict superalgebra of $M’$, I just meant $M_\omega’ \supsetneq M’$, or equivalently $M’ \subsetneq M_\omega’$.

Thanks! I have a question. Is $JM_\omega J$ a von Neumann algebra?

Of course, conjugation by $J$ is an anti-linear automorphism of $B(H)$, so $JNJ$ is a von Neumann algebra for any vNa $N \subset B(H)$. It is also always the case that $JNJ$ is anti-isomorphic to $N$, with the anti-isomorphism given by $N \ni n \mapsto Jn^\ast J \in JNJ$.

By the above statements，can we have the center $Z(JNJ)$ of $JNJ$ is equal to the $JZ(N)J$?

Yes, that is true. (The proof is really nothing more than writing down the definitions.)
